# If $D$ is dense, then for every open $U$ containing $x$, there exists an open $V \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in V \subset U$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces

I am currently trying to prove something related to dense and openness of sets:

> If $D$ is a dense subset of $X$ and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $\mathcal{B}_n = \left\{B\left(x, \frac{1}{n}\right) : x \in D\right\}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathcal{B}_n$, show that for every open set $U$ and $x \in U$, there exists a $V \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \subset U$.

My attempt is as follows, but am not sure if I am approaching this correctly, and what the next step would be.

**Attempt:** Let $U$ be an open set and let $x \in U$. Since $U$ is open, then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subset U$. Since $D$ is dense in $X$, then for every open set $U'$, $U' \cap D \neq \emptyset$ and so there exists an $x_0 \in U' \cap D$ such that $x \in B\left(x_0, \frac{1}{n}\right) \cap D$. Then taking $V = B\left(x_0, \frac{1}{n}\right) \cap D$, we have that $x \in V$, and $V \subset U$.

I am not entirely sure if this is the correct approach, so some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument seems to be ''almost'' correct. If I'm your teacher/teaching assistant, I may ask you "what is your $U'$ and $x_0$?

Here is a more precise way to choose $U'$ and $x_0$：

Just follow your approach, since $D$ is dense, $B(x, r)\cap D\ne\varnothing$ for any $r>0$,  we can pick $x_0\in B(x, \frac1n)\cap D$ for some $n$ large enough so that $\frac2n<\epsilon.$ (which also means $B(x, \frac1n)\subseteq B(x, \epsilon).$)

Therefore $x\in B(x_0,\frac1n).$ Now let $V=B(x_0,\frac1n).$ We see $x\in V$. And for any $y\in V,$ we have
$$d(x,y)\leq d(x,x_0)+d(x_0,y)<\frac1n+\frac1n=\frac2n<\epsilon,$$
which means $y\in B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U\implies V\subseteq U.$